# Random increment through a probability distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, gamma-distribution

*To Clarify i am trying to generate a random variable from a gamma pdf*

If $\Delta X$ indicates a random increment and it is said that
$\Delta X$ follows a Gamma distribution.

What would that mean exactly? How would you be able to get random variables from the Gamma distribution?

So far I understood the following, but am guessing this might be wrong:

$$ X\sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)\equiv\operatorname{\Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$$

This means $X$ follows a Gamma distribution so $\Delta X$ is a kind of sum of the different values $X$ takes at every iteration

$$g(x;\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}, \text{ for } x\geqslant 0\text{ and } \alpha,\beta>0 $$

so $X$ is represented by $x$ in the Gamma pdf, meaning I should put the value of $X$ for $x$ when computing the value of $X$ from the Gamma pdf?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: What do you call "computing the value of X from the Gamma pdf"? One does not "compute the value" of a random variable...

Comment: @Did Sure you can! Given $\omega\in\Omega$, one can compute the value of e.g. $X(\omega)$ (granted this is only possible if the function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is defined explicitly instead of in terms of its distribution).

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your comment. Is it related to the present page?

Comment: I was being facetious re: "One does not "compute the value" of a random variable" :)

Comment: @Math1000 And misleading to the OP, I am afraid.

Comment: @OP For your interest, the two current first sentences of your post "To Clarify i am trying to generate a random variable from a gamma pdf" and "If ΔX indicates a random increment and it is said that ΔX follows a Gamma distribution" contradict each other. The latter points at the simulation of *the increments of a process* while the former restricts the question to the simulation of a single random variable. Personally, I would bet on the latter (the process version). Providing the source of your question would allow to settle this.

Comment: actually ΔX would be the increment, so the need would be to generate random variables following the gamma pdf, these variables would then summed up

Comment: @Did Sometimes I forget that text is not often a good medium for sarcasm ;)

Comment: @AnarKi So, definitely the process version. Since you accepted an answer dealing with the single random variable version, you can deduce the former from the latter. How?

Comment: @Math1000 No problem, I might be too slow...

Comment: @Did again it would be the other way around generate a random variable that follows the gamma pdf and then generate another random variable the same for as many iterations as needed, or maybe i'm misunderstanding your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to generate gamma-distributed random variables.  If you want to write the code yourself, the way I know how is using the acceptance-rejection method by first generating an exponentially-distributed RV.  An exponential random variable $G$ with pdf $\lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda g}$ may be generated by first generating a uniform(0,1) random variable $U$ and applying the inverse transformation
$$
G = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(1-U).
$$
To generate a $gamma(\alpha,\beta)$-ditributed random variable, choose $\lambda = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ above and then use the [acceptance-rejection](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-ARM.pdf) method.

OTOH most scientific software includes these methods.  E.g. MATLAB's `gaminv(p,a,b)` could be used where $p$ is a uniform(0,1), $a = \alpha$ and $b = \frac{1}{\beta}$ (MATLAB uses the "other" version of the pdf you've given).  For example if you want to generate $1000$ gamma(2,3) random variables:

```
a=2;
b=1/3;
n=1000;
u=rand(n,1);
g=gaminv(u,a,b);
```

Comment: Perhaps see `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/` for more on acc-rej method.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is the pdf of the Gamma distribution with the correct parameters then for all real $x$,
$$\Pr[\Delta X < x] = F(x).$$
This defines the distribution of $\Delta X$ completely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I dont know if i understood the answer, how do you define x ?
∆X should be random so should there be a random process for defining x, i am sorry if i dont get it, could you explain in more depth ?

Comment: I'm not defining $x$. The equation is true for *all* $x$. For example, the probability that $\Delta X$ is at most $10$ is $F(10)$.